# What is the best way of converting roman numerals to arabic ones in bigquery?

Tags: sql, string, replace, google-bigquery

As in the title. The best thing that comes to my mind is using basic `REPLACE` function, but it fails with anything more complex than just `I`, `V`, `X` etc.

The Roman numerals in my data are located at the end of the string, so based on the well-known movie Fast & Furious my data looks like this:

| movie |
| --- |
| Fast & Furious I |
| Fast & Furious II |
| Fast & Furious III |
| Fast & Furious IV |
| Fast & Furious V |
| Fast & Furious VI |
| Fast & Furious VII |

Comment: What is the highest number you expect? A series of replacements may be the simplest. Just use the correct order: first try III, then II and last I (and so on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Roman numerals in my data are located at the end of the string

Consider below approach (along with some dummy data in addition to yours)

```
create temp function deromanize (number STRING) returns STRING 
language js as '''
  var number = number.toUpperCase(),
  validator = /^M*(?:D?C{0,3}|C[MD])(?:L?X{0,3}|X[CL])(?:V?I{0,3}|I[XV])$/,
  token = /[MDLV]|C[MD]?|X[CL]?|I[XV]?/g,
  key = {M:1000,CM:900,D:500,CD:400,C:100,XC:90,L:50,XL:40,X:10,IX:9,V:5,IV:4,I:1},
  num = 0, m;
  if (!(number && validator.test(number))) return false;
  while (m = token.exec(number)) num += key[m[0]];
  return num;
''';
with your_table as (
  select 'Fast & Furious I' movie union all
  select 'Fast & Furious II' union all
  select 'Fast & Furious III' union all
  select 'Fast & Furious IV' union all
  select 'Fast & Furious V' union all
  select 'Fast & Furious VI' union all
  select 'Fast & Furious VII' union all
  select 'Fast & Furious XXXIX' union all
  select 'Fast & Furious LXXI' union all
  select 'Fast & Furious MDCCLXXIV' 
)
select movie, 
  replace(movie, roman_number, deromanize(roman_number)) converted_title
from your_table, 
unnest([struct(array_reverse(split(movie, ' '))[offset(0)] as roman_number)])
```

with output

[image]